# How to remove white space in DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android

I have an extra space on the right of the `DatePickerDialog` when I launch the application on a large screen.

**Source code for Dialog :**

```
val datePicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { 
view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth -> if (view.isShown) { 
myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
 myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear) 
myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
 addTimer(isAct) 
}
 } 
DatePickerDialog(this, datePicker, myCalendar!! .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar!!.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
```

Could someone tell how to adjust it?

[image]

Comment: Post the code you use to show the picker, if you are using style or something post it as well

Comment: ` val datePicker = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            if (view.isShown) {

                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                addTimer(isAct)
            }
        }
        DatePickerDialog(this, datePicker, myCalendar!!
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar!!.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show() `

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout params as wrap content to remove your date picker dialog's white space. The dialog will be at the center of the window.
Try this one-

```
@Override
public void onStart() { 
    // This MUST be called first! Otherwise, the view tweaking will not be present in the displayed Dialog (most likely overridden)
    super.onStart();

    makeWrapContent(myCustomView);
}
```

A simple method to make wrap content of a view--

```
protected void makeWrapContent(View v) {

    View current = v;          
    do {
        // Get the parent
        ViewParent parent = current.getParent();    

        // Check if the parent exists
        if (parent != null) {
            // Get the view
            try {
                current = (View) parent;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                break;
            }

            // Modify the layout
            current.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
    } while (current.getParent() != null);

    // Request a layout to be re-done
    current.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML file as

Match parent to wrap content

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue. In my case, I was passing the dialog context instead of the activity's context.

Where are you showing the DatePickerDialog from? (from dialog, activity or fragment) Check what context is getting passed to the DatePickerDialog.

For a quick fix try passing the activity for the DatePickerDialog(activity,...)
So that it always gets the activity context.

Java
DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),...)

Kotlin
DatePickerDialog(activity,...)